# Handshake for peer 13 (x.x.x.x:51820) did not complete after 20 attempts, giving up

Tags: wireguard

Server Config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on ens3
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on ens3
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = 8CMdwwULGd4dGqbYmbt+6EV2BqyVqk8FLSWuJl1Tukk=

[Peer]
PublicKey = smVxzAVHG4/feMOwmbALKxEQkPYBIwKDzjTrZbbGIBE=
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32
Endpoint = 5.34.201.5:52856
```

Server Firewall:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8877                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
51820/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
51820                      ALLOW       Anywhere
8877 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
51820/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
51820 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Anywhere on ens3           ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on wg0
Anywhere (v6) on ens3      ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on wg0
```

and Server Network:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

========================================================

Now my peer config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = SLqo/o8boBWny/UFQhZ+AIolyZGtKrU7bNqsDPQg0GI=
Address = 10.8.0.2/24

PostUp = ip rule add table 200 from 5.34.201.5
PostUp = ip route add table 200 default via 5.34.200.1
PreDown = ip rule delete table 200 from 5.34.201.5
PreDown = ip route delete table 200 default via 5.34.200.1

DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = 4EECoZ8277EgjEAUsnSEC92uUSjXvOqpKz/+sEMizEQ=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 95.164.44.118:51820
```

and peer firewall:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
51820                      ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8877                       ALLOW       Anywhere
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere
47501                      ALLOW       Anywhere
51820/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
5000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
51820 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8877 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
47501 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
51820/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and peer network config:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Both server and peer are Ubuntu 22.04
and both sides run through:

```
wg-quick up wg0
```

on the server side when I enable log by:

```
echo "module wireguard +p" | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

I get almost nothing about wireguard
but when I enable logging in peer using:

```
sudo dmesg -wT
```

I get these messages and after 20 attempts it says given up!

```
[Wed Jun 21 23:02:59 2023] wireguard: wg0: Handshake for peer 14 (95.164.44.118:51820) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
[Wed Jun 21 23:02:59 2023] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 14 (95.164.44.118:51820)
```

I followed instructions based on this guide:
[here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-wireguard-on-ubuntu-20-04)

double-checked everything and also regenerated keys again but the same result.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I relized recently if I turn off ufw after running wg0 interface, peers will connect then, and I think something is wrong in firewall when the packet is going to be forwarded from server to peer